# Hyperlinking to a bibitem in LaTeX

Tags: hyperlink, latex

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib,xspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\BOGOS}{\hyperlink{BriEtal18a}{BOGOS}\xspace}

\begin{document}

In this article we reference \cite{BriEtal18a} many times.  I want to create the shortcut \BOGOS that will still link to the reference in the bibliography.  This does not work yet.

\begin{thebibliography}{}

    \bibitem[Briol et~al., 2018]{BriEtal18a}
    Briol, F.-X., Oates, C.~J., Griolami, M., Osborne, M.~A., and Sejdinovic, D.
    (2018+).
    \newblock Probabilistic integration: A role in statistical computation?
    \newblock {\em Statist.\ Sci.}
    \newblock to appear.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

If one clicks on the hyperlink for the citation it sends you to the reference.  If one clicks on my abbreviation, nothing happens.  I need to know what the right label is.  Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using [`natbib`](//ctan.org/pkg/natbib), you can define a citation *alias* which will be displayed instead of the regular `\cite`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\defcitealias{BriEtal18a}{BOGOS}% Define a citation alias
\newcommand{\BOGOS}{\citetalias{BriEtal18a}}% Use shorthand

\begin{document}

In this article we reference \citet{BriEtal18a} many times.
I want to create the shortcut \BOGOS{} that will still link to the reference in the bibliography.

\begin{thebibliography}{}

  \bibitem[Briol et~al., 2018]{BriEtal18a}
  Briol, F.-X., Oates, C.~J., Griolami, M., Osborne, M.~A., and Sejdinovic, D.
  (2018+).
  \newblock Probabilistic integration: A role in statistical computation?
  \newblock {\itshape Statist.\ Sci.}
  \newblock to appear.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```